# Is there any absolute index of app's performance in Xcode Instruments?

Tags: xcode, performance, core-animation, core-graphics, xcode-instruments

I've profiled my app with xcode instruments. Now I have a FPS log (see picture).  I'd like to have all FPS statistics in separate file (i.e. excel table) to analyze average fps or something more.
Can I do this? Is there any other way to get average fps or other absolute performance index of my application?
Thanks.

[image]